# Returning nothing in function if condition not met?

Tags: javascript, json, function, callback, zapier

I've been using Zapier's Code Steps to write code that sends variable information to the same Webhook.  I figured out how to do that when information needs to be sent however I only want the code to send the object(s) to the Webhook when the buy condition is true.  If `buy` is not true I want it to return nothing.

```
if(coins[i].buy===true)
{
fetch('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/974762/krbqch/', { method: 
'POST', body: "Coin:"+coins[i].coin +",Value:"+coins[i].currentValue 
+",Buy:" +coins[i].buy+",Sell:"+coins[i].sell+",Date:"+currentDate})
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }).then(function() {
    callback(callback(null, {}));
  })
  .catch(callback);
}
```

If the `buy` condition is false I will get an error of "Error: You must return a single object or array of objects."  This is important because most of the time `buy` will be false.  I realize that this is because there is no callback I just do not know what to put instead.  So what should I return if `buy` is false in order to prevent an error?

Comment: did you tried with `return false ` after the if statement , one more thing javascript assume everything is true unless it false , you could evaluate the condition like this `if(coins[i].buy)` , you dont have to ===true

Answer (score 2):

Going by the error, `Error: You must return a single object or array of objects.`

Zapier expects you to return an object or array of objects at the end.

You are doing that for the `buy === true` condition with this statement - `callback(callback(null, {}));`

Try doing the same outside the conditional block, just add the same line - 
`callback(null, {});`

This will return the `{}` to Zapier and your code step should succeed even when the condition is false.

Your code would look like this

```
if(coins[i].buy===true)
{
fetch('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/974762/krbqch/', { method: 
'POST', body: "Coin:"+coins[i].coin +",Value:"+coins[i].currentValue 
+",Buy:" +coins[i].buy+",Sell:"+coins[i].sell+",Date:"+currentDate})
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }).then(function() {
    callback(callback(null, {}));
  })
  .catch(callback);
}
callback(null, {});
```

More examples here:
https://zapier.com/help/code-examples/#introductory-http-example

You might want to get a new webhook URL as it is now public and anyone can trigger it.

I would recommend using the code block below - (Notice changes to the `callback` statement and removal of one `.then` block.)

```
if(coins[i].buy===true)
{
fetch('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/974762/krbqch/', { method: 
'POST', body: "Coin:"+coins[i].coin +",Value:"+coins[i].currentValue 
+",Buy:" +coins[i].buy+",Sell:"+coins[i].sell+",Date:"+currentDate})
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        callback(null, {});
    }).catch(callback);
}
callback(null, {});
```

Comment: @anthony-trischitti If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and select it as correct ([info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))